# polymer iron-list only loading 20 items

Tags: ajax, list, polymer, web-component

I have an a test array that I am retrieving from iron-ajax with around 1000 items.  I set that return array to the people property of my custom polymer element.  Iron-list is displaying the first 20 results, but when i scroll down the rest of the results are not being loaded.

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-list/iron-list.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html">

<dom-module id="people-list">
    <template>
        <iron-list items="[[people]]" as="item" class="flex">
            <template>
                <div style="background-color:white; min-height:50px;">[[item.city]]</div>
            </template>
        </iron-list>
        <iron-ajax 
            auto
            id="ajaxPeopleList"
            method="POST"
            url="/people/list"
            handle-as="json"
            last-response="{{people}}">
        </iron-ajax>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'people-list',
            properties: {
                people: {
                    type: Array
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

I think it may have to do with the height of the screen/iron-list element, but I am stuck and not sure how to proceed.

I can get it load all items if I set the height of the iron-list elements in pixels.  But I just want it to fit on the screen.  The docs make it look like you can use the iron-flex layout and use the class flex, which is what I tried to do in my sample code, but it has no effect.

Comment: Compare your code with the demo code here https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/tree/master/demo.  Try changing class="flex" in iron-list to class="layout vertical"

Comment: changed it, but that didn't help

Answer (score 5):

This is because nothing is firing the `iron-resize` event to tell the `iron-list` to redraw the items. According to the docs:

> ## Resizing
>
> `iron-list` lays out the items when it recives a notification via the `iron-resize` event. This event is fired by any element that implements `IronResizableBehavior`.
>
> By default, elements such as `iron-pages`, `paper-tabs` or `paper-dialog` will trigger this event automatically. If you hide the list manually (e.g. you use display: none) you might want to implement `IronResizableBehavior` or fire this event manually right after the list became visible again. e.g.
>
> `document.querySelector('iron-list').fire('iron-resize');`

I've added the following to your code (which is probably a bit of a hack) and got it working:

```
ready: function () {
  document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    // fire iron-resize event to trigger redraw of iron-list
    document.querySelector('iron-list').fire('iron-resize');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ben Thomas is right. You're getting the json elements but it's not displayed because the iron-list needs to be redrawn. Since i had the same problem, i went to google polymers website and found **[THIS](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/blob/master/demo/collapse.html)** code example.

In short for your example:

```
<script>
// Only execute after DOM and imports (in our case the json file) has been loaded
HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
  Polymer({
     is: 'people-list',
     properties: {
         people: {
             type: Array
         }
     },
    attached: function() {
      // Use the top-level document element as scrolltarget
      this.$.list.scrollTarget = this.ownerDocument.documentElement;
    }
  });
});
```